# how to add make a line-through in jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, line-through

i'd like to add a line-throught in my post, and i try like this:

~~hello,world~~

it's ok in my Mou(a software display markdown content), but it doesn't work in jekyll
,it tell me

`REXML could not parse this XML/HTML:`

i'm new to markdown, someone know that's why and how to fix it?
thanks~

Comment: Can you provide more source code? What engine do you use? maruku? redcarpet?

Comment: i just check it out from [here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), it may be Maruku: Default markdown engine (Ruby). then i just use rdiscount instead of it, it works!
thanks buddy!~

Comment: Yeah, there are different flavors of Markdown. Maruku, rdiscount and redcarpet are three rendering engines for jekyll, but there is also the Markdown used by GitHub (GFM), and other Markdown implementations with slighty different styles (PHP-Markdown, PHP-Markdown Extra). It can be quite a hell...

Comment: Most Markdown parsers support inline html, so `<s>hello, world</s>` should work.

Comment: i had change my default engine to rdiscount, and it's ok now. Thanks for your advise i'll try later also. @dbaupp